# Angular8 and formControlName with nested fields

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, formgroups

I spent many hours to solve this problem. My `formGroup` structure is:

```
 this.frameworkForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [null],
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      active: [true],
      parsingRequired: [false],
      reviewRequired: [false],
      frameworkSortingType: {
        id: null,
        environmentalSortingType: '',
        socialSortingType: '',
        governanceSortingType: '',
      },
    });
```

In my template I want to get value from eg. `environmentalSortingType`:

```
     <div class="alphabetically">
                      <label class="control-label bold-label" for="reviewRequired">Alphabetically</label>
                      <div class="p-field-radiobutton">
                        <p-radioButton [name]="'environmental'" value="alphabetically"
                                       formControlName="frameworkSortingType.environmentalSortingType"
                        ></p-radioButton>

 <p-radioButton [name]="'environmental'" value="numerically"
                                   formControlName="frameworkSortingType.environmentalSortingType"
                    ></p-radioButton>
                      </div>
```

But that solution with `.` like  `formControlName="frameworkSortingType.environmentalSortingType"` doesn't work. How to do that? I tried a lot of different ways... without success:(

**UPDATE**

I changed my code by adding nested formGroup but still I get the error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute (`<div class="sorting" formGroupName="frameworkSortingType">`)

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.frameworkForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [null],
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      active: [true],
      parsingRequired: [false],
      reviewRequired: [false],
      frameworkSortingType: this.formBuilder.group( {
        id: null,
        environmentalSortingType: '',
        socialSortingType: '',
        governanceSortingType: '',
      }),
    });
```

and my template:

```
  <div class="sorting" formGroupName="frameworkSortingType">
                <div class="alphabetically">
                  <label class="control-label bold-label" for="reviewRequired">Alphabetically</label>
                  <div class="p-field-radiobutton">
                    <p-radioButton [name]="'environmental'" value="alphabetically"
                                   formControlName="environmentalSortingType"
                    ></p-radioButton>
                  </div>
```

Comment: The problem is that you have used the variable `frameworkSortingType` as follows. `<div formGroupName="frameworkSortingType">`.  You need to see the picture carefully. It should be done `<div [formGroup]="frameworkSortingTypes">`

Comment: And inside that div, define the formControls belonged to `frameworkSortingTypes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [article](https://blog.angulartraining.com/managing-nested-and-dynamic-forms-in-angular-cc07f8682ab8), you can make `frameworkSortingType` as a new `FormGroup` and use this formGroup inside the main formGroup as follows.

[image]